Does the set of all homomorphisms form a ring?
I know that the set of all homomorphisms $f:G\to G$, where $G$ is a group forms a semigroup with identity with respect to the composition operation.
But does it form a ring with respect to addition and composition operations?

@BoweiTang Beg your pardon? $(f + f)(e_G) = f(e_G) + f(e_G) = e_G + e_G = e_G$.

@BenSteffan Right, silly mistake, sorry about that.

Rings assume that the addition is commutative so this can't be true in general. But it is true that if $(G, +)$ is abelian, $(\operatorname{Hom}(G,G), \circ, +)$ is a ring, where addition is treated pointwise.
The main point to check is that composition distributes over addition. If $f,g,h:G\to G$ then $(f\circ (g+h))(x) = f((g+h)(x)) = f(g(x)+h(x)) = f(g(x))+f(h(x)) = (f\circ g)(x) + (f\circ h)(x)$, so $f\circ (g+h) = f\circ g + f\circ h$.

why is addition not commutative?

@Isaac Since groups are not necessarily abelian groups. $f(a)+g(a)$ may not equal to $g(a)+f(a)$.

@Isaac I am defining addition to be the group operation, so if the group isn't commutative, the addition won't be either.

@AndrewDudzik, but if addition is normal addition i.e. plus "+". Isn't it commutative?

@Isaac Suppose I have two functions $S_3\to S_3$. What is your definition of the "normal addition" of those two functions?
